# Multi threading console app getting web requests

Tags: c#, multithreading

I currently have a console app which basically does an infinite loop and does a webrequest.

Currently it does a loop: gets a web request and then populates the results in the Mongo database. This has to be done for each request.

Which approach should I use to make this multi threaded?

Comment: System.Threading.Thread is a good one.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: No; it isn't.  Use TPL.

Comment: You actually want asynchrony, not threading.

Comment: @HanletEscaño : Bad advice. Async APIs are a much better choice.

Comment: You are right. I should have read the entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx), potentially set a maximum number of threads, and run the operation over your entire collection.

Be aware that multithreading will require you to synchronize access to your shared data.

That being said, in this scenario, most of your time is waiting on IO.  As such, using asynchronous method calls would likely be better than threading the operations, as threading will just block multiple threads unnecessarily.  MSDN has a nice [Walkthrough on Accessing the Web using Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh300224.aspx) which could be converted for your use.

Comment: Cheers will have a look at that. When i did try the parallel.for it caused issues due to webrequests and responses not being completed. But will have a look at the link.